# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'nazev_zanru' although it should have

Tags: python, django, django-models, attributeerror

Good day community, I need your help as I cannot proceed with my project. Django model.py returns an `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'nazev_zanru'`

My models.py is as follows;

```
from django.db import models


class Zanr(models.Model):
    nazev_zanru = models.CharField(max_length=80, verbose_name="Žánr")

    def __str__(self):
        return "Nazev_zanru: {0}".format(self.nazev_zanru)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Žánr"
        verbose_name_plural = "Žánry"


class Film(models.Model):
    nazev = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name="Název Filmu")
    rezie = models.CharField(max_length=180, verbose_name="Režie")
    zanr = models.ForeignKey(Zanr, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, verbose_name="Žánr")

    def __str__(self):
        return "Nazev: {0} | Rezie: {1} | Zanr: {2}".format(self.nazev, self.rezie, self.zanr.nazev_zanru)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Film"
        verbose_name_plural = "Filmy"
```

As far as I understand, the

```
def __str__(self):
    return "Nazev: {0} | Rezie: {1} | Zanr: {2}".format(self.nazev, self.rezie, self.zanr.nazev_zanru)
```

code refers through
 `zanr = models.ForeignKey(Zanr, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, verbose_name="Žánr")`
to

```
class Zanr(models.Model):
    nazev_zanru = models.CharField(max_length=80, verbose_name="Žánr")

    def __str__(self):
        return "Nazev_zanru: {0}".format(self.nazev_zanru)
```

` which is therefore defined. Where is the mistake? Migrations, URLs and admin done.

Thank you in advance, David

Comment: Did you make migrations and migrate?

Comment: You should have a query retuning null zanr fk, so zanr is None, and the it's trying to call None.nazev_zanru, which gives you attribute error

Comment: @geckos could you please be more specific? I'm new to Django and unsure about how to do apply your advice.

Comment: Look in your database for a film with null zarn, I guess this is what breaking your code. If you find it, fix `Film.__str__` method to handle this case

Comment: @geckos how do I look into the database? Did you mean something along these lines? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eAmC6Ympq0E

Comment: I mean do a query, connect to the database and do a query something like `select * from film where zarn = null`